# @ForeignCollectionField with multiple orderColumnName?

Tags: ormlite

I am using ORMlite to henbdle database operation for Android app.

I have foreign collection which I would like to order by using two columns instead of one:

Instead of current:

```
@ForeignCollectionField(eager = false, orderColumnName = "name")
private Collection<HistoricalFigureLink> historicalFigureLinks;
```

Something like this:

```
@ForeignCollectionField(eager = false, orderColumnName = "type,name")
private Collection<HistoricalFigureLink> historicalFigureLinks;
```

I have two workarounds - sort resulting collection manually with custom comparator after retrieving it or to retrieve collection with separate query - but I would like to avoid this kind of clutter.

Comment: Unfortunately, this currently is not supported by ORMLite.  Sorting the collection afterwards sounds like a good workaround.

Comment: Do you plan to add this ? Might be really useful, this sorting is already executed at the SQL level isn't it ?

Comment: just to update my previous comment, it is indeed added to the QueryBuilder in the BaseForeignCollection class. @gray Do you think an update to this could be done ? Could we have like a orderColumnNameRaw where the verifyColumnName shouldn't be done for the orderby. That would allow more flexibility no ?